# Multiple Inheritance via Composition

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, composition

Today in an interview i was asked if it is possible to do multiple Inheritance in JAVA, to which i said it can be achieved in a way by implementing multiple interfaces, but not exactly, to which she replied yes it is possible via Composition...
I am not sure if that's correct or not. If yes, then how exactly, can you explain in detail, with code snippets if possible...?

Comment: Off topic for SO, but if the interviewer is equating composition with multiple inheritance then you might not want to work there.

Comment: To underline @AndrewS 's comment, there is a concept known as  [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Composition and inheritance are different in a strongly-typed language like Java since a class is not of type `C` if the class has ha member of type `C` (i.e., utilizes composition). Your answer wrt. interfaces is not entirely correct, but as close as one gets to multi-inheritance in Java (at least for now).

Comment: @AndrewS Can you perhaps explain how this is off-topic?

Comment: Off topic since it's not about a specific programming question.  See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for details.  (I was not the down vote.)

Comment: @AndrewS This question is clearly about programming (that doesn't have to be about particular code snippets, does it?), and it's very clear.

Comment: it's conceptual - by _specific programming question_ I meant there is no code to consider as part of the question.  Arguably, **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development** from the help center would suggest it's acceptable.

Comment: As others have said, this is an opinion question, but I'm pretty cool with it. I think I agree with Andrew S above and also agree with the answer you gave in the interview. If object A includes an object B as a field, object A is still not a B, and you can't pass A to any methods that expect a B. You can give A all the actions of B, but it's still not a B and can't be passed as one. It's not inheritance. The interviewer is wrong, IMHO.

Comment: Is it possible to do Multiple Inheritance using Type intersections?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple inheritance of classes, it can do so only for interfaces.

Composition is a way of accessing certain methods/fields of an external class from your class in the following manner:

```
//This is a pseudo-code. Don't compile!
class YourClass{
    private ExternalClass obj;
    private AnotherExternalClass obj1;

    //initialize obj, obj1 in constructor

    public String getName(){
        return obj.getName();
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return obj1.getTitle();
    }
}

class ExternalClass{

    private String Name;

    //constructor to initialize Name ...

    public String getName(){
        return this.Name;
    }
}

class AnotherExternalClass{

    private String Title;

    //constructor to initialize Title ...

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

With this composition style of coding, the YourClass has now access to getName method of the ExternalClass, which the interviewer might be referring to as some type of "inheritance"

Comment: But i believe the above code snippet still doesn't show multiple-inheritance in JAVA right...?

Comment: @AkashAgarwal, yes it doesn't :) ... for "multiple-inheritance" you could store another field (say obj1) which points to a different class type and also implement its methods ... I made an edit to my answer ... see if it helps